# Create an entity class without @Entity annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to create an entity without @Entity annotation.

I have an employee class which is not annotated with @Entity.

Question:

1. How entity class is identified by JPA?
2. Is it possible to use custom annotation let say @MyOwnEntity instead of @Entity?
3. Is there is a way I can override JPA method to indicate package(com.mt.own.example) type are containing entity class? Note: I am going to annotate all the class within (com.mt.own.example) package with my own annotation.

Comment: 1) by having the @Entity annotation, 2) this is not a problem, 3) Probably but you will need to create your own setup for it

Answer (score -2):

i dont know why would you do that but yes you can ...

```
    @Documented
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface MyOwnEntity {
        String name() default "";
    }
```

Comment: This does absolutely nothing other than creating a unused annotation

Comment: but if you use it it will be used :D

Comment: How would you use it to mark an entity?

Comment: it might be possible by annotating `MyOwnEntity` with `@Entity`

Comment: @dan1st Can you explain more on your suggestion

Comment: If the implementation scanning for `Entity` supports it, you can do `@OtherAnnotations @Entity public @interface MyOwnEntity`.